# Create a multidimensional array in python without additional library?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def create_nd_array(dimensions, value):
"""Function will create a N-dimensional array.
    A N-dimensional array will be filled by the value being passed to the function.
Parameter:
Input:
    value(int or bool or string): Newly formed N-dimensional array will contain this particular value.
    dimensions(tuple): tuple indicating dimensions of newly formed N-dimensional array.
Output:
    array_nd(N-dimensional array): a N-dimensional array  of values."""
dimension_length = len(dimensions)
array_nd = value
for index in range(dimension_length - 1, -1, -1):
    dimension = dimensions[index]
    array_nd = [array_nd for _ in range(dimension)].copy()
return array_nd
```

I have written above code.
This will create a N-Dimensional array with aliasing.When I am mutating the list it will mutate everything.
e.g
[**aliasing problem**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkzKN.png) <--click here

Comment: Show inputs and desired outputs

Comment: `copy()` only returns a shallow copy. If you want a deepcopy you will need to use a different method, for example [`deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy).

Answer (score 0):

You need not `copy` the list, instead you can append it to a result list; and also instead of `range(dimension_length - 1, -1, -1)`, you can directly take the dimensions without using their indices by puttng `dimensions[::-1]` like this

```py
def create_nd_array(dimensions, value):
    array_nd = []

    for dim in dimensions[::-1]:
        array_nd.append([value for _ in range(dim)])

    return array_nd

print(create_nd_array((2,4,2), 0))
```

This can be further compressed into a List comprehension as

```py
def create_nd_array(dimensions, value):
    array_nd = [[value for _ in range(dim)] for dim in dimensions[::-1]]
    return array_nd

print(create_nd_array((2,4,2), 0))
```